# Where do I find Date class in Zend Framework 2.0?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have started my ZF2 application from Skeleton-Application.
I want instance of Date class in one of my controller.
I tried to search Date.php class under...

> library\Zend\

but could not found.
Does ZF2 has not Date.php at all or I need to palce it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Zend_Date has been removed in favor of PHP 5.3 DateTime API http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Thank you Maks3w. But how can i then use Date utilities in controllers? I mean which plugin or class should i intantiate for Date utilities?

Comment: I don't understand, Which Date utilities? almost all features of Zend_Date are provided by PHP 5.3

Comment: Maks3w, let say for example, in ZF 1.x it has wrapper class 'Zend_Date' (derived from Zend_Date_DateObject). 
 This class has friedly methods to operate on Dates like...
 Zend_Date::getUnixTimestamp
 Zend_Date::mktime
 Zend_Date::isYearLeapYear
 Zend_Date::dayOfWeek
 etc...
 My question is 'Does ZF2 has a wrapper class as 'Zend_Date' in ZF1.x? If not then do i need to use plain PHP Date statements throughout the code or need to write my own wrapper?'

Comment: No, the decision of ZF2 board was remove Zend_Date and don't supply any wrapper or other kind of friendly use. Personally I prefer to have a wrapper because, IMHO, PHP 5.3 DateTime API is very ugly and cryptographic

Comment: Thank you Maks3W for valuable information. As of now i will proceed with writing my own Plugin to wrap Date utilities.

Comment: Hanmant Please, when you finish send a Pull Request to the ZF2 GitHub repository to propose include your code with the framework

Comment: Hi again Maks3w, I just completed with my DateTime plugin for ZF2 [named as DateManager]. Actually I was needed it because my application is mostly oriented around date, time and timezone utilities. Written plugin is not a state-of-art one but it is good :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to call [DateTime()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) in Zend Framework 2 like base class.
Like:

```
$date = new \DateTime($str);
```

where `$str` is a string from which you create date object.