# Zend date validator fail for format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: php, validation, date, zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
<?php

  $dateString = '12.12.12';
  $dateCheckArray['format'] = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
  $validator = new Zend_Validate_Date($dateCheckArray);
  if ($validator->isValid($dateString)) {
      echo 'valid';
  }
  else {
      echo 'invalid';
  }
```

The code works ok for most formats, but for the one specified it fails when using a . date instead of a - date.

For example for the date specified before (12.12.12) the script will echo 'valid', even though it obviously doesn't fit the format.

Can anyone point out why this is happening?

Note: This is zend 1.

Comment: I am executed your code. It shows `invalid`.My version is `1.7`

Comment: That's strange. My version is 1.11.11. Rechecked... still valid.

Comment: Could you check your `date.php` in zend library.I think here you can find problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in [ZF-7583: Zend_Date::isDate accepts invalid dates](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7583). Thats why some dates are showing in correct. Its better to use a regex validation for it.

You can check this post for the regex [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Only about 6 years since some1 pointed out that bug :)). Nice... feeling trust in Zend going down.

Comment: @zozo It seems they have solved the issue [Where do I find Date class in Zend Framework 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401221/where-do-i-find-date-class-in-zend-framework-2-0)

Comment: It is fixed in 2.0, but can't exactly port the whole project over night :). 1.x and 2.0 are not exactly compatible. Anyway... solved. Ty 4 helping.

Comment: actually its not fixed :). Please check the link.

Comment: Hm... worked fine on my test yesterday. Maybe got in a particular case.