# Location of Zend_Date PHP class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-date

I'm trying to use the `Zend_Date` class for my project. I'm working with the PHP Storm IDE and I've searched throughout the ZF2 folder which is included in my project under the:

```
/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ -> now it should be somewhere here but I couldnt've find it in the folder structure...
```

I've also tried doing the  following in code:

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
```

but it prints out the following error:

```
Undefined class Zend_Date
```

Where am I supposed to find the `Zend_Date` class, and if it's not included in my folder structure, where can I get it ?

Comment: I think you need to download Zend framework into you project. It's a class in zend framework. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.introduction.html  I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I find Date class in Zend Framework 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401221/where-do-i-find-date-class-in-zend-framework-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Date` is a  class from Zend Framework 1. You seem to be using Zend Framework 2. Don't mix ZF1 and ZF2 functionality.

There is a `DateTime` class in ZF2 (`Zend\Stdlib\DateTime`) but it has been deprecated as of ZF 2.1.4. Use the PHP `DateTime` class instead. Docs can be found [here on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).